# How to expose Vue as global object

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I am integrating legacy code with newer one, built with Webpack. In legacy code, plain js accessed Vue simply with: `new Vue(...)`, from global scope. In Webpack, Vue will get sucked into vendor bundle and I would like to expose Vue back, so my legacy code would still see it as window.Vue

What I have done so far (webpack 3.x):

```
{
  test: require.resolve('vue/dist/vue.esm.js'), 
  use: [{loader: 'expose-loader',
         options: 'Vue'
   }]
 }
```

I get close with this, but I end up with window.Vue.default having **the** instance. How do I shim it further?

Comment: Do you want to expose your main Vue instance? or just the Vue library?

Comment: I want to expose the library.

Comment: Have you tried using `require.resolve('vue/dist/vue.esm.js').default` ?

Comment: @Ricky, that blew up the compiler :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can get it to `window.Vue.default` then how about just adding a line of code after that's available (but not within WebPacked js) that is

```
 app = window.Vue.default;
```

Then Vue will be globally available from the `app` object.

Comment: that did work. TY. But I am still confused about one minor point. When I load webpack bundled js via <script>, and then have an anonymous <script>window.Vue = window.Vue.default</script> that follows it, it seems I am not always guaranteed the order of execution to be just right. I'm guessing because modules within __webpack__ wrapper functions get executed in sequence of require_this_and_that() calls and not sequence of <script> tags?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not as familiar with WebPack as I'd like to be so I'm not sure how to guarantee that `window.Vue.default` is available from WebPack.  However, Vue is gonna have to auto execute so that it can process the vue directives and templates on the page so I another approach could be to  add a `created` method to the vue instance and set it to `created: function () { window.app = this;}`  This will ensure that once vue is created it set's the app global to it's instance.  Then Vue will be globally available from the `app` object.