# Expose Vue3 to global scope in Wepback

Tags: vue.js, webpack

In Webpack, I'm adding `vue.global.prod.js` into a bundle and attempting to expose `Vue` with `expose-loader` for use in other bundles.

I'm aware this question [Use Webpack to expose Vue to globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59888524/use-webpack-to-expose-vue-to-globally) allows Vue2 to be exposed, however I've been unable to expose Vue3 in a similar fashion.

As a last resort I could just add `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>` so it exposes `Vue` but I assume there must be a solution via Webpack?

Answer (score 0):

In Typescript, I managed to solve it this way:

main.ts

```
import * as Vue from 'expose-loader?exposes=Vue!vue'

...

global.Vue = Vue;
```

or via the webpack.config.js

```
...
{
    test: require.resolve("vue"),
    loader: "expose-loader",
    options: {
        exposes: [{
            globalName: "Vue",
            moduleLocalName: "default",
        }]
    },
},
```

and then in main.ts you can

```
import * as Vue from 'vue'
...
global.Vue = Vue;
```